# Calculus system expansion to complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Does calculus for complex numbers exists?
did any one ever tried to make research on this?

What would it mean to have complex numbers calculus? 
for instance:
What is the meaning of $$\lim_{x\to z} f(x) = L \\ for \ complex \ values  \ z, L, \ and \ the \ complex \ variable \ (x)$$

What is the meaning of $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\sqrt {-1}$$

Or what's the meaning of $$\int_{z_2}^{z_1} F(z) dz = \sqrt {-1},\ for \ complex \ values \ z, z_1, z_2$$

Comment: You may want to learn [complex analysis][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis].

Comment: Yes, it's called complex analysis and it has been studied for a couple of centuries alongside its real counterpart.

Comment: Yes - in fact the question of the integral is more interesting, because if we are integrating between two complex numbers we have to specify a path in the complex plane along which to integrate and different paths can give different values for the integral. The theory is rich and there are some surprising results.